# How to set a limit on data scanned by a user in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, bigdata, limit, quota

Is there a way to set a limit on a user to not query data of more than a particular size in a table.

Eg - If a user uses 'Select' command, he should be limited to query a certain amount of data irrespective of the query he writes.

I have been trying to follow this link - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set quotas at the project-level or at the user-level. Be careful though since it is not possible to assign a custom quota to a specific user or service account.

You can set quotas by following this steps in the cloud console:

1. Go to quotas page
2. Select only BigQuery service
3. Look for Query usage per day per user or Query usage per day and select it
4. Click on Edit Quotas
5. Set the limit on the right side, validate and Submit

More information:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/custom-quotas
https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#managing_your_quota_console

Comment: Does query usage mean the data scanned? I have seen we can put a limit on the number of queries.

Comment: Correct, check out these examples: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/custom-quotas#example

Comment: Can we also set a limit on query level? 
Ex - a query should not scan more than X TB of data.